# Replace does not substitute in function

Tags: replacement

I have the following expression with functions

```
Ricci11=-(Derivative[1][a12][u]^2/(
  a12[u]^2 - 
   a11[u] a22[u])) - (-((a22[u] Derivative[1][a11][u])/(
    2 (a12[u]^2 - a11[u] a22[u]))) + (a12[u] Derivative[1][a12][u])/(
   2 (a12[u]^2 - a11[u] a22[u])))^2 + (
 Derivative[1][a11][u] Derivative[1][a22][u])/(
 a12[u]^2 - a11[u] a22[u]) - (
 a22[u] Derivative[1][a11][
   u] (-a22[u] Derivative[1][a11][u] + 
    2 a12[u] Derivative[1][a12][u] - a11[u] Derivative[1][a22][u]))/(
 2 (a12[u]^2 - a11[u] a22[u])^2) + (
 a12[u] Derivative[1][a12][
   u] (-a22[u] Derivative[1][a11][u] + 
    2 a12[u] Derivative[1][a12][u] - 
    a11[u] Derivative[1][a22][u]))/(a12[u]^2 - a11[u] a22[u])^2 - (
 a11[u] Derivative[1][a22][
   u] (-a22[u] Derivative[1][a11][u] + 
    2 a12[u] Derivative[1][a12][u] - a11[u] Derivative[1][a22][u]))/(
 2 (a12[u]^2 - a11[u] a22[u])^2) - ((a12[u] Derivative[1][a12][u])/(
   2 (a12[u]^2 - a11[u] a22[u])) - (a11[u] Derivative[1][a22][u])/(
   2 (a12[u]^2 - a11[u] a22[u])))^2 - 
 2 ((a12[u] Derivative[1][a11][u])/(2 (a12[u]^2 - a11[u] a22[u])) - (
    a11[u] Derivative[1][a12][u])/(
    2 (a12[u]^2 - a11[u] a22[u]))) (-((a22[u] Derivative[1][a12][u])/(
     2 (a12[u]^2 - a11[u] a22[u]))) + (a12[u] Derivative[1][a22][u])/(
    2 (a12[u]^2 - a11[u] a22[u]))) + (
 a22[u] (a11^\[Prime]\[Prime])[u])/(2 (a12[u]^2 - a11[u] a22[u])) - (
 a12[u] (a12^\[Prime]\[Prime])[u])/(a12[u]^2 - a11[u] a22[u]) + (
 a11[u] (a22^\[Prime]\[Prime])[u])/(2 (a12[u]^2 - a11[u] a22[u]))
```

and I want to replace parts of it with 
`m[u_] = {{a11[u], a12[u]}, {a12[u], a22[u]}}`, for which `\[Chi][u_] = (Det[m[u]])^(1/4)`.

To do that, I typped `Ricci11/.(-a12[u]^2+a11[u]a22[u])^(1/4))->\[Chi][u]`, however, the substitution is not made and the expression stays the same...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: With the definitions you have made `\[Chi][u]` is identical to `(-a12[u]^2 + a11[u] a22[u])^(1/4)` so no changes can occur. I am confused as to the expression your are trying to replace and the replacement expression you wish to use.

Comment: Do you want to have `\[Chi][u]` displayed in the expr? Or `(Det[m[u]])^1/4`?

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused but if you use your definition of `Riccil1` and make the replacement without defining `m[u_]` it would look like the following. First I remove the power to the 1/4 on each side and multiple both sides by negative one.

```
Ricci11 /. a12[u]^2 - a11[u] a22[u] -> -Det[m[u]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.